# How can i display on a datatable array data using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'm using a MongoDB database to store some data. I now want to display this data on a HTML Datatable.

The data i'm trying to use is stored in arrays, here is how it is structured:

```
data: [[1848, 84857], [4944, 4949], [34, 65], [3566, 78], .... ]

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
        "columns": [

            {"data": 'data'},

        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

The problem with my actual code is that it will display the datatable like this:

```
    DATA:
[[1848, 84857], [4944, 4949], [34, 65], [3566, 78], .... ]
```

While i would like it like this:

```
    DATA:
1848, 84857
4944, 949
36, 65 and so on
```

How can i fix this issue? I was thinkin with a foor loop, but i don't really know how to do that, since i'm calling the data straight in the `table` variable.

The json response is something like this:

```
{"data":"[[11756.53, 2.419583] .....
```

Comment: May i know your ajax response structure, if you inspected from network tab F12 of your browser

Comment: Adding it right now!

Answer (score 1):

You are using **array of array** data, just use index key to map your columns:

```
"columns": [
          {"data":0},
          {"data":1}
        ]
```

**Awesome Example below:**

```js
function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
$.mockjax({
    url: "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
    response: function(settings) {
      this.responseText = {
        "draw": settings.data.draw,
        "recordsTotal": 4,
        "recordsFiltered": 4,
        "data": [
          [randomIntFromInterval(400, 8000), 84857], 
          [4944, 4949], 
          [34, 65], 
          [3566, 78]
        ]
      }
    }
});


var editable=false;

$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mytable').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "/endpoint/?format=datatables",
        "columns": [
          {"data":0},
          {"data":1}
        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mockjax/1.6.2/jquery.mockjax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="mytable" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Just one thing, can you explain what is the mockjax function doing? I tried using 0, but it's throwing an error

Comment: @Jack022 mockjax is a Jquery API mocking for ajax request/response. Its for testing only. You can use Datatables without mockjax as you will use real ajax link.

Comment: Ok, got it! So i tried editing the column data to be like this: {data: 0} but it still doesn't work, i'm now trying to see why it failed from my console

Comment: @Jack022 Did you try "columns": [{"data":0}, {"data":1}] ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i'm trying!

Comment: @Jack022 Try remove your whole columns option.